# Cannot read data that send in pusher private channel when user is connect to the pusher

Tags: laravel, nuxt.js, pusher, channel, laravel-events

The user connect to the pusher but not subscribe to private channel and the data send with the event the private channel and cannot access to it.

Here is my event in Laravel:
[BlogCreatedEvent in Laravel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uJCVz.png)

Here is my channel in Laravel:
[channel in channels.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wuXAT.png)

Here is my code to listen to this channel:
[listen code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/byZ0s.png)

Here is what I get in pusher debug console:
[pusher debug console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zaOCE.png)

so as you can see I connected to the pusher but when I send event I cannot read the data in this event!!
Anyone can explain that?